# why does source tree look for gpg keys while I haven't configured for signing?

Tags: git, gnupg, sourcetree

I downloaded [sourcetree app](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) on my mac and added a local git repo to it. Whenever I try to stash something or commit something, sourcetree throws gpg related errors. An example error is as below.

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree stash save test-stash 
/Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/bin/gpg: line 2: gpg2: command not found
error: gpg failed to sign the data
Cannot save the current index state
Completed with errors, see above
```

I am unable to figure out the cause for this error. As far as I remember, I have not configured either the project or sourcetree app for any sort of signing.

It'd be of a great help if you could help me with troubleshooting this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if I try committing from command line, it asks for gpg keys.

After a lot more search on internet I found the root cause. It was due to one of the dotfiles that set the global config for signing commits in `~/.gitconfig` as true. Therefore, I set the config back to false using following command.

```
$ git config --global commit.gpgsign false
```

Phew! The issue is resolved now...

Answer (score 0):

After a few tries, found out that following instructions below helped:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/setup-gpg-to-sign-commits-within-sourcetree-765397791.html

The issue was that with a brand new El Capitan and Source Tree install, there doesn't seem to be a `gpg` binary.

The above article goes through the steps to download the Mac GPG tools and how to set it up.

Key is to configure SourceTree to explicitly sign the commits, otherwise, it tries to use the system git preferences, which somehow creates another problem as explained here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/sourcetreekb/sourcetree-commits-fail-when-using-git-signed-commits-794199810.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer @HanSooloo. But my was more about 'why gpg is being asked in the first place?. I have not configured my git project for it. I have not configured source tree for it. Then why?'. After two days of more searching on internet, I got the answer.